# ¿Cómo puedo rellenar media estrella al pasar el mouse?

Tags: html, css

Tengo una calificación de estrellas y quiero que al pasar el mouse por la mitad del ícono se rellene de un color, por la otra mitad se termine de rellenar con el mismo color: algo similar a la calificación de play store; mejor dicho, rellenar la mitad del ícono y luego al pasar el mouse la otra mitad del ícono, para que la calificación se dé de 0,5 a 5, 1 a 5, 1,5 a 5 y así hasta llegar de 5 a 5.

```css
.fichas-listado-v2 .voto .voto-estrellas{
  display: block;
  unicode-bidi: bidi-override;
  direction: rtl;
  width: 50%;
  margin-top: 40px;
}
.fichas-listado-v2 .voto .voto-estrellas i{
  color: #d41217;
  font-size: 53px;
  padding-right: 3px;
}

.fichas-listado-v2 .voto .voto-estrellas i:hover{
  cursor: pointer;
  color: #d41217;
}
.fichas-listado-v2 .voto .voto-estrellas i.fa-star,
.fichas-listado-v2 .voto .voto-estrellas:hover i{
  color: #c0c0c0;
}
.fichas-listado-v2 .voto .voto-estrellas:hover i:before{
  content: "\f005";
}
.fichas-listado-v2 .voto .voto-estrellas i.fa-star-o:hover:before,
.fichas-listado-v2 .voto .voto-estrellas i:hover ~ i:before{
  content: "\f005";
  color: #d41217;
}
```

```html
<html>
  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.5.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="fichas-listado-v2">
      <div class="voto">
        <div class="voto-estrellas">
          <i class="fa fa-star-o"></i><i class="fa fa-star-o"></i><i class="fa fa-star-o"></i><i class="fa fa-star-o"></i><i class="fa fa-star-o"></i>
        </div>
      </div>
     </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 3):

esto te puede ayudar, para que funcione hice unos cuantos cambios y utilice un engaño visual con solapado de capas

```css
.voto-estrellas{
  position: relative;
  width: 200px;
}
.fichas-listado-v2 .voto .voto-estrellas{
  //display: block;
  direction: rtl;
 // width: 50%;
  margin-top: 40px;
}
.fichas-listado-v2 .voto .voto-estrellas i{
  color: #d41217;
  font-size: 53px;
  padding-right: 3px;
}

.fichas-listado-v2 .voto .voto-estrellas i:hover{
  cursor: pointer;
  color: #d41217;
}
.fichas-listado-v2 .voto .voto-estrellas i.fa-star,
.fichas-listado-v2 .voto .voto-estrellas:hover i{
  color: #c0c0c0;
}
.fichas-listado-v2 .voto .voto-estrellas:hover i:before{
  content: "\f005";
}
.fichas-listado-v2 .voto .voto-estrellas i.fa-star-o:hover:before,
.fichas-listado-v2 .voto .voto-estrellas i:hover ~ i:before{
  content: "\f005";
  color: #d41217;
}

.fa-star-o{
  overflow: clip;
}

i.fa-star-o:nth-child(10){
  color: pink;
  position: absolute;
  left:20px;
  z-index:30;
 }

i.fa-star-o:nth-child(9){
  color: pink;
  position: absolute;
  left: 45px;
  z-index:40;
  width:25px;
 }

i.fa-star-o:nth-child(8){
  color: pink;
  position: absolute;
  left:70px;
  z-index:30;
 }

i.fa-star-o:nth-child(7){
  color: pink;
  position: absolute;
  left: 95px;
  z-index:40;
  width:25px;
 }
i.fa-star-o:nth-child(6){
  color: pink;
  position: absolute;
  left:115px;
  z-index:30;
 }

i.fa-star-o:nth-child(5){
  color: pink;
  position: absolute;
  left: 140px;
  z-index:40;
  width:25px;
 }

i.fa-star-o:nth-child(4){
  color: pink;
  position: absolute;
  left:165px;
  z-index:30;
 }

i.fa-star-o:nth-child(3){
  color: pink;
  position: absolute;
  left: 190px;
  z-index:40;
  width:25px;
 }

i.fa-star-o:nth-child(2){
  color: pink;
  position: absolute;
  left:215px;
  z-index:30;
 }

i.fa-star-o:nth-child(1){
  color: pink;
  position: absolute;
  left: 240px;
  z-index:40;
  width:25px;
 }
```

```html
<html>
  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.5.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="fichas-listado-v2">
      <div class="voto">
        <div class="voto-estrellas">
          <i class="fa fa-star-o"></i>
          <i class="fa fa-star-o"></i>
          <i class="fa fa-star-o"></i>
          <i class="fa fa-star-o"></i>
          <i class="fa fa-star-o"></i>
          <i class="fa fa-star-o"></i>
          <i class="fa fa-star-o"></i>
          <i class="fa fa-star-o"></i>
          <i class="fa fa-star-o"></i>
          <i class="fa fa-star-o"></i>
        </div>
      </div>
     </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

No esta al 100% pero allí te tocará pulir el CSS

Comment: tengo un probelma en esta parte del codigo: .fichas-listado-v2 .voto .voto-estrellas i.fa-star,
.fichas-listado-v2 .voto .voto-estrellas:hover ~ i{
  color: #c0c0c0;
}  no he logrado hacer que se rellene de girs las demas estrellñas, mientras la primera esta de rojo